# python decimal gives wrong answers

Tags: python, decimal

This is something you can try in the interpreter, can anyone explain me why?
Note: This problem is different from [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) because my answers are not a little off, but way off and my question is about decimal, not about the built in float.

```
from decimal import getcontext, Decimal
a = Decimal(".110001"+"0"*17+"1"+"0"*95+"1"+"0"*599+"1"+"0"*4319+"1")
b = Decimal(".220002"+"0"*17+"2"+"0"*95+"2"+"0"*599+"2"+"0"*4319+"2")
b-a == a # Returns False while it should be True
b-a-a # Returns Decimal('-1.000000000000000000000000000E-120')
```

Comment: Just to complete the picture: "[...] not a little off, but way off [...]". That's not true. `-1.000000000000000000000000000E-120` is very little. And presumably, overlooking the scientific notation is the very crux of the matter here.

Comment: The linked duplicate is not a good one: it's primarily about errors resulting from floats being stored in binary internally (the What You See Is Not What You Get nature of binary floating-point when expressed in decimal), and it doesn't help with diagnosis or solution of this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default `Decimal` precision is 28 decimals, so you are loosing data, `b - a` is `0.1100010000000000000000010000`. You can set it with `getcontext().prec`

```
a = Decimal(".110001" + "0" * 17 + "1" + "0" * 95 + "1" + "0" * 599 + "1" + "0" * 4319 + "1")
b = Decimal(".220002" + "0" * 17 + "2" + "0" * 95 + "2" + "0" * 599 + "2" + "0" * 4319 + "2")
getcontext().prec = max(len(str(a)), len(str(a)))
print(b-a == a) # True
```